# Python trying fails

Tags: python, try-catch

I am trying in Python.

```
try:
    newbutton['roundcornerradius'] = buttondata['roundcornerradius']

buttons.append(newbutton)
```

buttons is a list. roundcornerradius is optional in buttondata.

Alas this gives

> ```
> buttons.append(newbutton)
>       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

I just want to ignore the cases where roundcornerradius does not exist. I don't need any error reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why arent you using the `except` keyword

```
try:
    newbutton['roundcornerradius'] = buttondata['roundcornerradius']
    buttons.append(newbutton)
except:
    pass
```

this will try the first part and if an error is thrown it will do the except part

you can also add the disered error you want to except a certain error like this

`except AttributeError:`

you can also get the excepted error by doing this:

`except Exception,e: print str(e)`

Comment: I fixed it, using the "except: pass". buttons.append(newbutton) should be outside though or it wouldn't add buttons that don't have roundcornerradius set ;-)

Comment: Awesome Try\except blocks are actually very useful! Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should catch a try with exception:

```
try:
   code may through exception
except (DesiredException):
  in case of exception
```

Also you can use `else` with try if you need to populate new buttons only when try succeeds:

```
try:
    newbutton['roundcornerradius'] = buttondata['roundcornerradius']
except KeyError:
    pass
else:
   buttons.append(newbutton)
```

single `except:` with no exception class defined will catch every exception raised which may not be desired in some cases.

Most probably you will get `KeyError` on your code but I am not sure.

See here for builtin exceptions:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html

Answer (score 0):

You must close block with `except` or `finally` if using `try`.

```
try:
    newbutton['roundcornerradius'] = buttondata['roundcornerradius']
except KeyError:
    pass#omit raise if key 'roundcornerradius' does not exists
buttons.append(newbutton)
```

If you know default value for `'roundcornerradius'` - you dont need no `try ... except`

```
newbutton['roundcornerradius'] = buttondata.get('roundcornerradius', DEFAULT_RADIUS)
buttons.append(newbutton)
```